# how to convert a full text from a file to a dataframe in a single column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a text document containing a topic on an article:

I constantly hold my urge to write how-to's on basic 101 topics, since I strongly feel that there is already enough content on the internet. However, after seeing people reading through tutorials after tutorials, watching video after video.

I want to convert it into a data-frame in a single column and a single row

this is what I have tried:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
file_name = "foot.txt"
file = open(file_name, "r")
filedata = file.readlines()
file = " ".join(filedata)
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(file))

df.T.to_csv('data.csv', header=True)

result_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',)
result_df.head()
```

Comment: there is only one line on all txt files?

Comment: yea, this is a result of text i get from scraping a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use separator `'\n'` and `header=None` parameters on `pd.read_csv`:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'foot.txt',sep='\n',engine='python',header=None)
```

Output:

```
df
    0
0   I constantly hold my urge to write how-tos on basic 101 topics, since I strongly feel that there is already enough content on the internet.However, after seeing people reading through tutorials after tutorials, watching video after videos,
```

​